# Android Studio cannot resolve androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider but produces working app non the less

Tags: android, android-studio

So I wanted to start my project from a bottom navigation template in Android Studio 4.1.2. It loaded the template (failed to load plugins for editing navigation - but i assume that's non related).

Then I've noticed the lint in the generated UI code. No reasonable fixes were suggested by the IDE, and I couldn't ctrl + LMB the class to view It's source either.
I've looked on S.O. for similar issues, but most of them actually missed the class and were solved by tweaking project dependencies, while mine seem to still work on my android device without any issues.

I'm not sure if this is some linting false positive, indexing issue, or something else - but invalidating cache, restarting the IDE or the entire PC doesn't yield anything.

Could anyone suggest as to why could this happen? Is this indeed just the visual's or could the app be built without that class and still work (doubt that, but just to clarify)? What could i try to get rid of that annoying issue?

[image: IDE Screenshot]
[image: Device Screenshot]

Upon further inspection I also noticed that I can view source of other classes in the package `androidx.lifecycle` without any issue. `ViewModelProvider` also is not suggested by autocompletion as an import option. I tried commenting out the import thinking that maybe due to some weird circumstances it's in another file or package, but IDE still did not find any other import possibilities.

Comment: `or could the app be built without that class and still work` try it?

Comment: @a_local_nobody as i mention in the question, i did - it does. The issue is that i don't know whether linting is broken but the dependency is built and used, or the app still functions even with the missing dependency.

Comment: if it compiles it most likely works, restart android studio or reinstall it, probably just false positive

Comment: @a_local_nobody as i mentioned, i tried reinstalling, rebuilding, invalidating cache, restarting both IDE and PC.

Comment: did you try `build->clean project` then rebuild it? If the compilation is performed errorless, then the error is definitely from the IDE and not from your code.